# How to update nested list table using activate framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I have two entities `Task` and `Comment`. There is a list of `Comment` in `Task` entity. When I post a new comment for particular task, how should I do? Should I create a new Comment first? If I create a new `Comment`, how can database know it is belong to which task?

Here are my enitities:

```
case class Task (
    var title: String,
    var description: String,
    var estimate: Int,
    var time_start: String,
    var time_end: String,
    var state: String,
    var created_at: String,
    var created_by: String,
    var modified_at: String,
    var modified_by: String,
    var members: scala.collection.immutable.List[User],
    var comments: scala.collection.immutable.List[Comment])
      extends Entity

case class Comment (
        var content: String,
        var created_at: String,
        var edited_at: String,
        var last_comment: String)
      extends Entity
```

I use `createTableForAllEntities` for creating tables and there is a table created automatically:

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.TASKCOMMENTS(
    OWNER VARCHAR(1000),
    VALUE VARCHAR(45),
    POS INTEGER
)
```

I think I need to update that nested list table, but how to?

And there is a thing I found in play's tutorial:

*When you are using repeated data like this, the form values sent by
the browser must be named emails[0], emails[1], emails[2], etc.*

So I think I should edit json of task by this way, but how to?

I try to create a new comment first, and get it from database. Then using

```
val toUpdate = new EntityMap[Task](oldT)
val oldComments = toUpdate.get(_.comments).getOrElse(List())
val newComments = oldComments :+ newC
toUpdate.put(_.comments)(newComments)
transactional(toUpdate.updateEntity(oldT.id))
```

It still can't update comments!

Comment: which database are you using, and what is the tutorial you are following? Could you give a link to it?

Comment: h2, and the tutorial is https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms

Comment: It looks like in your case, this method doesn't to the right thing. As far as I can see in the docs, it's not even guaranteed to do so: http://activate-framework.org/documentation/migration/ I'd rather create the tables in the more "regular" Slick way (if you use Slick to persist your data)

Comment: I used regular way to generate table Task but got error said that Task already exists